# Delete local accounts in windows using cmd script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hello I created simple script to remove windows local users.

```
@echo off
set /p username= Enter the name of account which you want to delete : 
net user /DELETE %username%
pause
```

The only problem is if the users are many I need to run the script for each user again and again.
I need to make it working with many users. When cmd prompt me about name I should be able to enter them with comma or just single space, collect them in array, later delete them with foreach or some loop function. How to make it with cmd?

Comment: Directly from [[tag:cmd]]: ```For %G In (UserName1,"User Name 2",UserName3,"User&Name4") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %G /Delete``` or ```For %G In (UserName1 "User Name 2" UserName3 "User&Name4") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %G /Delete```. From a [[tag:batch-file]]: ```@For %%G In (UserName1,"User Name 2",UserName3,"User&Name4") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %%G /Delete```, or ```@For %%G In (UserName1 "User Name 2" UserName3 "User&Name4") Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %%G /Delete```. The quotes are for usernames which contain spaces or poison characters.

Comment: To expand a little… If you want to enter your names at a prompt from the batch file itself, i.e. ```@Set /P "UserNames=Enter the account names for deletion>"```, you'd type ```UserName1,"User Name 2",UserName3,"User&Name4"```, or ```UserName1 "User Name 2" UserName3 "User&Name4"```, then press the `[ENTER]` key. Your code would then look like this: ```@For %%G In (%UserNames%) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %%G /Delete```. If the names don't contain spaces/poison characters, you can just type ```UserName1 UserName2,UserName3, UserName4```, separating them using spaces, commas or both.

Comment: Can I ask how to create many accounts with password again with similar script? I managed when I changed /Delete with /Add but I need to make different password for each account

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Compo the script is working perfect (run as administrator)

```
@Set /P "UserNames=Enter the account names for deletion: "
@For %%G In (%UserNames%) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe User %%G /Delete
```